# columns in the visualforce page not displaying correctly in the Ipad

Tags: visualforce

columns in the visualforce page  not displaying correctly in the Ipad.the below is the screen shot.[image]

but desired output is below,[image]

and below is the my visual force page code ,

```
<body>   

<style> 
.sf1outputText {font-family:  "ProximaNovaSoft-Regular", Calibri; font-size: 19px;color: #2f4476 ;display: block;min-width: 100px;}  

.sf1label {font-family: "ProximaNovaSoft-Regular", Calibri;font-size: 16px;color: #2f4476;display: block;min-width: 50px;}
.message{color:#ff4000;line-height:40px;font-size: 19px;}
 </style>

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
    <!--For salesforce desktop  -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$User.UITheme != 'Theme4t'}">
         <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__Street__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__Total_Travel__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__City__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.SF1Geolocation__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__State__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__Auto_Geocode__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__Zip__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.Generate_Confirmation__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__Country__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="sf1outputText " rendered="{!($User.UITheme == 'Theme4t'&& !IsAppointmentDay)}">
            The day selected is not the day of the appointment.  You are not able to view appointment details until the day of the appointment.  Please contact your sales manager for any questions.
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <!--For iphone mobile Salesforce1  -->
        <!--<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!($User.UITheme == 'Theme4t'&& IsAppointmentDay)}">-->
        <apex:pageBlock>
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" rendered="{!($User.UITheme == 'Theme4t'&& IsAppointmentDay)}">
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__Street__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__Total_Travel__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__City__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.SF1Geolocation__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__State__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__Auto_Geocode__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__Zip__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.Generate_Confirmation__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!CKSW_BASE__Service__c.CKSW_BASE__Country__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>            
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

```
</html>
```

could you please suggest me,How to dispaly it correct format in Ipad.

Thanks,
Madhava.

Comment: Madhav looks like apart from header, no element go styleshit. Are you able to see proper output on safari, chrome?

Comment: I am to see the output as first screen shot in Ipad,But I am looking for the 2 nd output.Thanks In Advance..<apex:page standardController="CKSW_BASE__Service__c" extensions="SF1AppointmentAddressExtension" tabStyle="CKSW_BASE__Service__c">
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="iPad" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
    </head>
    
    <body>    the above code is missing.

Comment: What I wanted to say is first check it in normal chrome safari browser on desktop and inspect there.

Comment: Hi Kiran,
I have checked it normal chrome browser,only half portion of the page is occupied by these 2 columns.

Comment: So are facing same issue on chrome desktop. Please try inspecting that one. Once you fix it on desktop mode then go for iPad.

Comment: ok I will update you ASAP